# How to create a doctype with TagBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

The `!` in the doctype tag I cannot create. Is there a way to put the ! in a doctype tag using tagbuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [Doctype is not an HTML tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp), you can't use TagBuilder.

Although, you can return a normal MvcHtmlString.

```
public static class CustomHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DocType(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            var docType = @"<!DOCTYPE ...>";
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(docType);
        }
    }
```

And then use it like that:

```
@Html.DocType()
```